# reactjs KeyboardDatePicker + react hook form: How to get the date in YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am using material ui + react hook form for my form

```
          <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <Controller
              name="date_of_birth"
              control={control}
              defaultValue={new Date()}
              render={({ field: { ref, ...rest } }) => (
                <KeyboardDatePicker
                  inputRef={ref}
                  margin="dense"
                  fullWidth
                  id="date-picker-dialog"
                  label="Date of Birth"
                  format="yyyy-MM-dd"
                  KeyboardButtonProps={{
                    "aria-label": "change date",
                  }}
                  error={errors.date_of_birth ? true : false}
                  {...rest}
                />
              )}
            />
          </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

With the in the react hook form i get `date_of_birth` in the format `2021-08-29T00:46:27.103Z` but i want it to be `2021-08-29`

HOw can i do this

**Tried**

```
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
const dateFns = new DateFnsUtils();

... in the onSubmit function
... example
date = dateFns.parseISO('2021-08-29T01:23:43.495Z')
... here i get error parseISO is not a function of dateFns
formated = dateFns.format(date,"yyyy-MM-dd")
```

How to use dateFns to format it to yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: Just format it when you want to use like submit

Comment: I have edited the question. I am using date-fn but get `parseISO` is not a function

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in their document. Just use the format function.

https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started

Updating my answer:

For date formatting purposes you may use date-fns or moment.js. @date-io is an abstraction of various date libraries like moment, date-fns, luxon, etc. In your case, you can directly use date-fns library and use their features.

Comment: ok. But I am just curious why parseISO function is not found. Its there in the docs. is this something to do with `@date-io/date-fns`

Comment: As per documents import { parseISO } from 'date-fns.

Comment: are `@date-io/date-fns` and `'date-fns` different. Do i have to install `date-fns`.

Comment: Someone already gave a negative for my answer. If your purpose is to deal with date formatting you can simply use https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns. If you need additional features from @date-io/date-fns which I highly doubt, you can use that. @date-io/date-fns is an abstraction of various date libraries like moment, date-fns.

Comment: ok. thats what confused me. Seeing date-fns at two places